# duscird.js get the name of the user involved

Tags: node.js, discord.js, commando

I have a command in which one user virtually kisses another

The output is a message `@User1 kissed @User2`

But I want that instead of tags on the user, only names were written, like this so that it was `user1 kissed user2`

In theory, everything should work like this

```
`**${message.author.username}** kissed **${userToKiss.username}**`
```

But if the name for `message.author` is defined, then there is none for `userToKiss` and I end up with this

`user1 kissed undefined`

How can I get the name for the second user?

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class KissCommand extends Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'kiss',
      memberName: 'kiss',
      group: 'reywl',
      description: 'Kiss the mentioned user',
      guildOnly: true,
      args: [
        {
          key: 'userToKiss',
          prompt: 'Please select the member you want to kiss.',
          type: 'member',
          default: 'isempty',
          wait: 0.0001
        }
      ]
    });
  }
  
  run(message, { userToKiss }) {
    if (userToKiss == 'isempty') {
        return message.channel.send('Please select the member you want to kiss.')}
    if (userToKiss.id == message.author.id) {
      return message.channel.send('You cant kiss yourself!');
    }
    else {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`**${message.author}** kissed **${userToKiss}**`)

        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
    setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 1000)
}};
```

Comment: the person (user2) that is entered in the command, will turn into the guild member's ID number.  then you can use a guild.members.fetch(user2ID), and get the guild member object, and then extract the name from there

Comment: @G-Force I don't understand how to do it, I get an error `An error occurred while running the command: ReferenceError: guild is not defined`

Comment: @G-Force this is how it works `const kissed = message.guild.members.fetch(userToKiss.id)` 
but how can I get the username from there now? like this doesn't work `${kissed.username}`

Comment: remember that there is a difference between GuildMember object and User.  A GuildMember object has somethin called displayName (handy as it covers both the name and nickname cases) and a User has username property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deep explanation for your work, to do this you need to code first about the member, we always do about `member` and `author`

Author is for the author itself and the member for your members who are you going to call

I don't know if `commando` and normal command handlers are the same but here's the code what you wanted.

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first() //this is the way how you ping a member
${member.user.username} //the word user is the user member
```

for the author you can only do this

```
${message.author.username}
```

You can also ping a member using their Id's

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
${member.user.username}
```

So the main output is

```
${message.author.username} kissed ${member.user.username}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```
const kissed = await message.guild.members.fetch(userToKiss.id);

${kissed.user.username}
```